# Does 'System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom' modify the native DLL search order?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, loadlibrary

I have the following situation:

```
base\C_sharp.exe -> base\sub\CPPCLI.dll -> base\sub\CPPnative.dll
```

where I have a C# executable, loading a C++/CLI (.NET) dll via [`System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx) that is statically linked to `CPPnative.dll`.

Now, the [Standard Dll Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows is:

1. The directory **from which the application loaded**.
2. The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
3. The 16-bit system directory. (...)
4. The Windows directory. (...)
5. The current directory.
6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.

Obviously, if I call

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\....\base\sub\cppcli.dll");
```

the .NET assembly will be found, but what then happens is that the transitive load of the `cppnative.dll` succeeds!

```
1618:3088 @ 1557218328 - LdrLoadDll - ENTER: DLL name: D:\....\base\sub\cppcli.dll DLL path: D:\....\base\sub\;;C:\Windows\system32;...
...
1618:3088 @ 1557218328 - LdrpHandleOneOldFormatImportDescriptor - INFO: DLL "D:\....\base\sub\cppcli.dll" imports "cppnative.dll"
...
1618:3088 @ 1557218328 - LdrpLoadImportModule - ENTER: DLL name: cppnative.dll DLL path: D:\....\base\sub;;C:\Windows\system32;
```

**TL;DR**: How does the native NT loader suddenly start looking in the `sub` directory?

Normal `LoadLibrary` behaviour would suggest that the executable directory is searched first.

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility that the .NET framework is using `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` internally when eventually doing the `LoadLibrary` call to the C++/CLI assembly.

At least, I can clearly see in my call stacks that the framework *is* using `LoadLibraryEx` internally to load the mixed mode cppcli.dll into the process.

First:

```
>   cppnative1.dll!DllMain(HINSTANCE__ * hModule, unsigned long ul_reason_for_call, void * lpReserved) Line 13  C++ Symbols loaded.
    cppnative1.dll!dllmain_dispatch(HINSTANCE__ * const instance, const unsigned long reason, void * const reserved) Line 199   C++ Symbols loaded.
    ntdll.dll!LdrpRunInitializeRoutines()  Unknown Symbols loaded.
    ntdll.dll!LdrpLoadDll()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
    ntdll.dll!LdrLoadDll() Unknown Symbols loaded.
    KernelBase.dll!LoadLibraryExW()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
    [Managed to Native Transition]      Annotated Frame
    mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool throwOnFileNotFound, bool forIntrospection, bool suppressSecurityChecks)    Unknown No symbols loaded.
```

Then:

```
>   cppcli.dll!DllMain(HINSTANCE__ * hModule, unsigned long ul_reason_for_call, void * lpReserved) Line 17  C++ Symbols loaded.
    cppcli.dll!dllmain_dispatch(HINSTANCE__ * const instance, const unsigned long reason, void * const reserved) Line 199   C++ Symbols loaded.
    mscoreei.dll!000007fef3ec0e64() Unknown No symbols loaded.
    mscoree.dll!000007fef5fd3281()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    mscoree.dll!000007fef5fd32cf()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    ntdll.dll!LdrpRunInitializeRoutines()  Unknown Symbols loaded.
    ntdll.dll!LdrpLoadDll()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
    ntdll.dll!LdrLoadDll() Unknown Symbols loaded.
    KernelBase.dll!LoadLibraryExW()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
    [Managed to Native Transition]      Annotated Frame
    mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool throwOnFileNotFound, bool forIntrospection, bool suppressSecurityChecks)    Unknown No symbols loaded.
```

I can also observe, that the executable path *is no longer searched* when resolving the transitive (native) module dependencies during this `LoadLibraryEx` call.

That is, all transitive (native) dependencies MUST reside in the directory of the `LoadFrom` call, not in the application directory.

(Incidentally the CWD "." *is* searched, so that can add to the confusion as well.)